# Why does my managed beans are not working?

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, managed-bean

I've installed a primefaces theme and then when I run the project some xhtml files don't display well. I inspected the code and I realize that there instead of putting the css link in the href tag there is a RES_NOT_FOUND message.  Th `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-#{guestPreferences.theme}.css" library="ecuador-layout" />` I'm trying to access the variable of the css file name with a managed bean. I think there is a problem with the managed bean. All the managed beans in the project are not working. Please help me. I've spent a month on this problem.

I tried to find some dependencies on the web in order to fix the problem. When i replace the  #{guestPreferences.theme} by the variable name  `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-amber.css" library="ecuador-layout" />` everything works fine but when I'm trying to access some pages which include a call to a managed bean I get an error.

Comment: @BalusC I've already read your explation on link above but I still don't know how to fix the problem. I had the same project on another computer and it is working fine. I think that there is something that I forgot to install. You said that it is not a jee problem and not a primefaces problem neither. Can you please tell what should I do exactly in order to solve my issue?

Comment: I've finally found the problem The problem was with my username. There was a blank space in my username. I've got the username changed and everything started to work fine. @BalusC